# Malfunctioning java.util.Calendar in Android

Tags: java, android, time, calendar, broadcastreceiver

Having a difficult time with learning Android programming, though I suspect that the problem isn't necessarily Android itself. I am attempting to make a (toggleable) auto-silencer, setting the phone to vibrate once school starts and to regular mode once it ends. It also must not force this; i.e. it only changes it once per change in time (e.g. if I set the phone to vibrate while outside of school hours, it won't change it back the next minute). Here's my code:

```
public class TimeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    boolean previousState;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        switch (day) {
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                if (((hour == 7 && minute >= 40) || hour >= 7) && ((hour == 13 && minute <= 45) || hour <= 13)) {
                    if (!previousState) {
                        manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                        previousState = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (previousState) {
                        manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                        previousState = false;
                    }
                }
                return;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                if (((hour == 7 && minute >= 30) || hour >= 7) && ((hour == 14 && minute <= 40) || hour <= 14)) {
                    if (!previousState) {
                        manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
                        previousState = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (previousState) {
                        manager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                        previousState = false;
                    }
                }
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Against all logic, or at least I hope against simple boolean logic, the ringer disables itself at 7:00 AM exactly (rather than 7:40 on Mondays and 7:30 on other days), and re-enables itself at 2PM exactly on Mondays (rather than 1:45) and 3PM exactly on other days (rather than 2:40). I simply do not know how it could produce this result. Thoughts?

Also, registration code in case it matters:

```
TimeBroadcastReceiver receiver = new TimeBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
{
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    if (!this.enabled && enabled) {
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        this.enabled = true;
    } else if (this.enabled && !enabled) {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        this.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

This is called from a service.

Comment: In the expression `(hour == 7 && minute >= 40) || hour >= 7` you meant to say `hour > 7`, not `hour >= 7`. Similar for all the other expressions. As you can see, it's not the `Calendar` that is malfunctioning, but your code.

Comment: @Andreas Jesus, I'm stupid. Thanks.